# Two selectInputs in tabPanel (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shinydashboard and in the dashboardBody()-function I have a tabBox with a tabPanel. In there are two selectInputs which I'd like to be next to each other. But independent of their size the second one is automatically put below the first one although there would be enough space next to it. Does somebody know how to force the selectInputs to be next to each other?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code to your app, or a simplified example of it.

Comment: @aeq Can you accept the answer if it was helpful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `style` in `div` tag you can do this as below:

```
 library(shiny)
 runApp(list(
   ui = fluidPage(
      div(style="display:inline-block",selectInput("input1", label="Input 1", choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2))),
      div(style="display:inline-block",selectInput("input2", label="Input 2", choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2)))
   ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
))
```

This gives you two selectInput next to each other as you can see in below image:

[image]